# C# how to add Await to this function - SendEmailAsync - MailKit in Dot Net Core

Tags: asp.net-core, async-await, mailkit

I have code based on [MailKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit). Where do I add the await keyword?

```
public async Task SendEmailAsync(string email, string subject, string mess)
{
    var message = new MimeMessage();
    message.From.Add(new MailboxAddress("Joey Tribbiani", "joey@friends.com"));
    message.To.Add(new MailboxAddress("Mrs. Chanandler Bong", "chandler@friends.com"));
    message.Subject = "How you doin'?";

    message.Body = new TextPart("plain")
    {
        Text = @"Hey Chandler"
    };

    using (var client = new SmtpClient())
    {
        // For demo-purposes, accept all SSL certificates (in case the server supports STARTTLS)
        client.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (s, c, h, e) => true;

        client.Connect("smtp.friends.com", 587, false);

        // Note: since we don't have an OAuth2 token, disable
        // the XOAUTH2 authentication mechanism.
        client.AuthenticationMechanisms.Remove("XOAUTH2");

        // Note: only needed if the SMTP server requires authentication
        client.Authenticate("joey", "password");

        client.Send(message);
        client.Disconnect(true);
    }
}
```

This is a similar implementation (but I couldn't find credential to make this work) so I changed to the above

```
    public async Task SendEmailAsync(string email, string subject, string message)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri("smtp.gmail.com") })
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic",
                Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("api:key-*")));


            var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
            {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("from", "postmaster@sandbox*.mailgun.org"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("to", email),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("subject", subject),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("text", message)
            });

            await client.PostAsync("sandbox*.mailgun.org/messages", content).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What API is this? Are there Task-based asynchronous methods?

Comment: @mikez In core it's there, I am new to core though

Comment: "In core it's there." I don't know what you mean by that. It looks like MailKit. [Read the documentation](http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/T_MailKit_Net_Smtp_SmtpClient.htm). There are Task-based async methods for all of this.

Comment: None of that Mailkit API you have shown is async, so you can't just add an await. Remove the async keyword and you have a working method. You could then run that whole method from Task.Run or something.

Comment: @HenkHolterman is there any method that support async

Comment: You'd have to go through the MailKit API, look for methods with ASync in the name and/or those that return a Task or Task<T>.

Comment: @HenkHolterman okay

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using .Net core and MailKit, you should reference the MailKit libraries and send via those. My MailKit class for sending email is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using MailKit.Security;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using MimeKit;
using SmtpClient = MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpClient;

namespace App.Email
{
    public class MailKit : IMailKit
    {
        private readonly ILogger<MailKit> _logger;
        private readonly Settings _settings;

        public MailKit(ILogger<MailKit> logger, IOptions<Settings> settings)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _settings = settings.Value;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Sends an email asynchronously using SMTP
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="toEmailAddress"></param>
        /// <param name="subject"></param>
        /// <param name="bodyHtml"></param>
        /// <param name="bodyText"></param>
        /// <param name="retryCount"></param>
        /// <param name="toName"></param>
        public async void Send(string toName, string toEmailAddress, string subject, string bodyHtml, string bodyText, int retryCount = 4)
        {
            var message = new MimeMessage();

            message.From.Add(new MailboxAddress(_settings.MailKitFromName, _settings.MailKitFromAddress));

            message.To.Add(new MailboxAddress(toName, toEmailAddress));

            message.Subject = subject;
            var builder = new BodyBuilder
            {
                TextBody = bodyText,
                HtmlBody = bodyHtml
            };
            message.Body = builder.ToMessageBody();

            for (var count = 1; count <= retryCount; count++)
            {
                try
                {
                    using (var client = new SmtpClient())
                    {
                        client.LocalDomain = _settings.MailKitLocalDomain;
                        client.Authenticate(_settings.MailKitUsername, _settings.MailKitPassword);

                        SecureSocketOptions secureSocketOptions;

                        if (!Enum.TryParse(_settings.MailKitSecureSocketOption, out secureSocketOptions))
                        {
                            secureSocketOptions = SecureSocketOptions.Auto;
                        }

                        await client.ConnectAsync(_settings.MailKitHost, _settings.MailKitPort, secureSocketOptions).ConfigureAwait(false);
                        await client.SendAsync(message).ConfigureAwait(false);
                        await client.DisconnectAsync(true).ConfigureAwait(false);
                        return;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception exception)
                {
                    _logger.LogError(0, exception, "MailKit.Send failed attempt {0}", count);
                    if (retryCount >= 0)
                    {
                        throw;
                    }
                    await Task.Delay(count * 1000);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Interface

```
namespace App.Email
{
    public interface IMailKit
    {
        void Send(string toName, string toEmailAddress, string subject, string bodyHtml, string bodyText, int retryCount = 4);
    }
}
```

Comment: IMailKit is the interface class that contains the single Method declaration.

You will need to implement that as well as look at loading the settings. 

I am assuming that you know asp.net core and have read the MailKit documentaion. You cant expect to just add the file to your project and everything will work. If you don't think this is an answer, then wait for better ones.

Comment: Added the interface, but you will need to look at the documentation, and apply the provided code accordingly.

Comment: This is app settings within your project that holds your email settings. You will need to look up how to use app settings in .net core. If you want to do that later, just remove references to the settings and hard code the values in (I recommend looking up how to implement settings and not use hard coded values)

Comment: I haven't completed configuring Appsetting, the credentials are bit confusing for me. I couldn't find the right values for configuring gmail server.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [async functions](https://csharp.hotexamples.com/examples/MailKit.Net.Smtp/SmtpClient/SendAsync/php-smtpclient-sendasync-method-examples.html) like this:

```
public class Notification
{
    public Notification() { }
    private string emailSubject,receiverEmail,emailBody;

    public string EmailSubject { get => emailSubject; set => emailSubject = value; }
    public string ReceiverEmail { get => receiverEmail; set => receiverEmail = value; }
    public string EmailBody { get => emailBody; set => emailBody = value; }

    public async Task<bool> sendEmail(){
        try
        {
            var message = new MimeMessage();
            message.From.Add(new MailboxAddress("Smart Living", "smartliving321@gmail.com"));
            message.To.Add(new MailboxAddress("Person", receiverEmail));
            message.Subject = emailSubject;
            message.Body = new TextPart("plain")
            {
                Text = emailBody
            };
            using (var client = new SmtpClient())
            {
                await client.ConnectAsync("smtp.gmail.com", 587, false);
                await client.AuthenticateAsync("smartliving321@gmail.com", "living@smart1122");
                await client.SendAsync(message);
                await client.DisconnectAsync(true);
                //                client.ServerCertificateValidationCallback=();
            };
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {

            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this my simple solution, now I can send email with MailKit from IdentityServer in a asp core project.

```
public class EmailSender : Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI.Services.IEmailSender
{
    private readonly EmailConfiguration _emailConfig;
    public EmailSender(EmailConfiguration emailConfig)
    {
        _emailConfig = emailConfig;
    }

    public Task SendEmailAsync(string email, string subject, string htmlMessage)
    {
        var message = new MimeMessage();
        message.From.Add(new MailboxAddress(_emailConfig.FromName, _emailConfig.FromEmail));
        message.To.Add(new MailboxAddress(email.Trim().ToLower(), email.Trim().ToLower()));
        message.Subject = subject;
        message.Body = new TextPart("html") { Text = htmlMessage };

        using (var client = new SmtpClient())
        {
            try
            {
                client.Connect(_emailConfig.SmtpServer, _emailConfig.Port, MailKit.Security.SecureSocketOptions.SslOnConnect);
                client.Authenticate(_emailConfig.UserName, _emailConfig.Password);
                client.Send(message);
                client.Disconnect(true);
                return Task.FromResult(true);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
            }
        }
    }
```

and in startup.cs -> ConfigureServices

```
        var emailConfig = Configuration.GetSection("EmailConfiguration")
            .Get<EmailService.EmailConfiguration>();
        services.AddSingleton(emailConfig);
        services.AddScoped<IEmailSender, EmailService.EmailSender>();
```